# Hyperlinks A HREF do not work

Tags: xhtml, hyperlink, wordpress-theming, href, broken-links

I'm a bit fooling around with a new website idea. But when i was testing it the A HREF does not work. It's not even showing a finger/hand pointer.

It's the text at the content area (the first white block under the header, **but not the menu**). The headers should be links to the posts (Wordpress).

screenshot of the links that do not work (red arrows):
http://new.go80.nl/screenshots/brokenlinksscreen.png

Actually all the links in that area do not work.

And at the Contact page not even the google maps work.
I can't move around and can't click the links.

Can somebody please help me figure this out? I don't want to start over.

Website: http://new.go80.nl/headlines

**EDIT, i first linked to the home page. Beacouse I'm new here i could only add one link and the home page actually is OK so I linked to the Headlines page.**

Thank you guys very much!

Greetings, Joeri Kosters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `z-index: -1` in your `global.css` in your `#content` id section. Remove this and your problem is fixed.

The z-index is making all of the `#content` links unreachable by the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like focus is going to the pagewrap div by default

EDIT #2: Make sure you give an example that actually shows the problem : )

It looks like somehow you've gotten `z-index: -1` on `div#content`, so it is falling 'behind' `div#pagewrap` and so is not clickable.  Get rid of that and you should be fine.

Comment: Like i commentented to Oli Charlesworth, the WebKit Inspector thinks there is. And the Google Maps on the contact page is not working too, you can't move it around and use the links in it. I guess it's the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, as I am new here i could only put in 2 links. So I linked to the Home page. This is actually the page without links. It's on the Cases, Headlines, and Contact page. (links will follow).

Comment: @JoeriKosters I figured it out, see above : )

Comment: Man you marked the guy that just commented as the answer?  Argh. (No offense random dude)

Comment: @Dave: Dude check the times, I totally beat you to it by 2 minutes. :P Oh, and none taken. :)

Answer (score 2):

Umm, you haven't put this text inside `<a></a>` elements, according to the HTML source.

Comment: @JoeriKosters: That's neither the web-page nor the HTML that you've actually linked to.  Click on the link in your question, press Ctrl+U, then search for "About the company".

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. It's on the Headlines and Cases page only. And there is also something weird on the Contact page. The google maps do not work properly. But as I am new here i could only use 2 links. The direct links will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Umm just put those headlines text in between the "a" and href tags.

```
   <a href="http://yourlink/link.htm">Your Heading</a>
```

Comment: If you go to the Headlines page you see it is. The Home/About page is actually the only one without links. http://new.go80.nl/headlines