# Hyperlinks do not work

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in the head section of [my website](http://www.startupsandfinance.com/). I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508641/hyperlinks-a-href-do-not-work) question but my css does not seem to have a z-index.The image and the like box display but nothing happens when I click them or I should say that the hyperlinks do not work. Please help out. Thanks

```
  <div class="content-pad" style="float:left;">               
                <a href="mailto:developerfahaduddin@gmail.com"><img src="http://www.startupsandfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Advertise-here-728x90.png" width="728" height="90" /></a> 
                <span class="widget-pad" style="margin-left:25px;"> 
                <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FStartupAndFinance&amp;width=290&amp;height=62&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;appId=384169901601437" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:290px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> 


                </span>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your div.content has no height.

Answer (score 4):

When you click on the header image, the default email application is launched as you have an **href** to:

```
mailto:developerfahaduddin@gmail.com
```

You can check it out live in here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MSRXU/

So, is something else that you haven't write the code for.

After looking at your page with Firebug, I see something else is messed up. If you add some height to:

```
<div class="content">
...

</div>
```

You will be fine, and the image will be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.content` has no height, and pointer events are not reaching the iframe because it is outside of it's parent element's boundaries.

Adding this rule to whatever else you have for your `.content` selector.

```
div.content {
    height: 120px;
}
```